# how to solve my compiler warning

Tags: php, sql, syntax

Whole code:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['usname']) && isset($_POST['pasw'])){

    $username = mysql_ramznegar($_POST['usname'],$link);
    $password = mysql_ramznegar($_POST['pasw'],$link);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `usname` = $username";
    $admin_result = mysql_query($query,$link);
    $admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC);

    if($admin_result['usname']==$username && $admin_result['passw']==$password){


            if($admin_result[usname] == "admin"){

            $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;

                redirect("panel");

                   exit;                                

    }
     else{

        echo 'ur username or password is invalid';
        redirect("index.php");
     }


}

}

?>
```

I have a database with a table (admin) with two columns, first one is `usname` and second one is `passw`,and I select the query nevertheless when I enter username and password compiler show this error to me, how can I resolve this compiler warning:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramznegar1\index.php on line 60
>
> You should change
>
> $admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)
>
> To
>
> $admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($admin_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)

I edited my code ,but again I encountered with this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ramznegar1\index.php on line 60

new code is : http://pastebin.com/ycNT0XqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should change:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `usname` = $username";
$admin_result = mysql_query($query,$link);
$admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `usname` = $username"; 
$admin_result = mysqli_query($query,$link); 
$admin_result = mysqli_fetch_array($admin_result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php for info on how mysql_fetch_array works

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
 $admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

To

```
 $admin_result = mysql_fetch_array($admin_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

PHP DOC ON mysql_***

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: @JOYE BRIGHT i would need to see your new code .. update the question or add it to pastbin ...

Comment: @JOYE BRIGHT have seen your code ... you forgot to connect to the mysql database ..... `$link` should be like ` $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');` ???? something like that

Comment: i attach this function by including the other file before html code started,i attched whole file,http://pastebin.com/1t378mqt

Comment: +why don't you just put it before ur select statement

Comment: i'm sure that there isnt any problem for connecting or selecting db,the error indicate problem on mysql_fetch_array()